# How can I create a copy of an Oracle table and add new columns to it in same statement?

Tags: oracle, create-table

How can I create a copy of an Oracle table and add new columns to it in same statement? I guess there should be some function. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try this way

```
CREATE TABLE TEST02
AS
SELECT  COL1                            AS COL3
,       CAST(COL2 AS VARCHAR2(20))      AS COL4
,       CAST(NULL AS DATE)              AS COL5
FROM    TEST01;
```

**Note:** I assumed the new column to hold NULL values.
COL1 and COL2 is already present in Table 1 and copied into Table 2 as COL3 and COL4 where as COL5 is newly created

Comment: don't forget he may wish to transfer constraints as well.

Comment: Not in scope. :) If needed then need to rethink as well ;)

Comment: haha, fair enough... I just thought of copying a table as copying all the metadata about the table as well(and now to come to think of it, the actual data as well) ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot realspirituals, it works perfectly for me :)